# How to run a program in its own, temporary, xdisplay (runx)?

Tags: scripts, xorg

For background I like to play some older games that really run better in super low resolutions and having the whole desktop switch to 320 x 400 is really not that great.

I've gotten around this by logging into a tty and running `startx` as needed. Running the game in the new display with minimal desktop acceleration and interference.

This is a painfully manual process and I am looking to streamline it.

The closest thing to a guide to do this I found is on an archwiki page:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_program_in_separate_X_display

However, the script in that page is not really compatible with Ubuntu's setup as I've found out of the box, and it does a lot of sloppy things that I'd rather avoid or do as elegantly as possible. I was unable to really achieve a complete runx by myself.

How can I run a program in a new (temporary) xdisplay?

Comment: What commands do you use manually? We can script it.

Comment: Wouldn't `xterm command` allow you to run your program in it's own window so you could ajust it as you see fit?